# Safely & portably read a value into a predefined integral type of varying size like mode_t

Tags: c, parsing, integer, type-safety, portability

I need to read a value from a text file and put it into a predefined type, in this particular case `mode_t`. This typedef can have a variety of types underlying it, so what is the portable way to read such a value and assign it to a variable of the predefined type.

Since you have no idea how large the type is, I was starting under the assumption that you should read using `strtoimax`/`strtoumax` and then range check somehow.  What I came up with "works" (seemingly) but looks ugly to my eye.

For example:

```
static mode_t parse_mode ( const char * s ) {
    char *       e = NULL;
    uintmax_t    u;
    uintmax_t    x;
    mode_t       m;
    int          c;

    if ( s == NULL) goto error_no_value;
    if (*s == '\0') goto error_no_value;
    if (*s == '-' ) goto error_negative;
    errno = 0;
    u = strtoumax(s, &e, 8);              /* value is in octal */
    if (errno) goto error_range;
    if (e == s) goto error_bogus;
    c = *e;
    if (c && !isspace(c)) goto error_bogus;   /* WS after is OK */

    /* now the question part -- better way??? */
         if (sizeof(mode_t) == 1) x = UINT8_MAX;
    else if (sizeof(mode_t) == 2) x = UINT16_MAX;
    else if (sizeof(mode_t) == 4) x = UINT32_MAX;
    else if (sizeof(mode_t) == 8) x = UINT64_MAX;
    else goto error_what_size;
    if (u > x) goto error_too_big;

    m = (mode_t)u;
    return m;
error_no_value: fprintf(stderr, "Error: no value\n");    return (mode_t)-1;
error_negative: fprintf(stderr, "Error: negative\n");    return (mode_t)-1;
error_range:    fprintf(stderr, "Error: range\n");       return (mode_t)-1;
error_bogus:    fprintf(stderr, "Error: bogus\n");       return (mode_t)-1;
error_what_size:fprintf(stderr, "Error: what size\n");   return (mode_t)-1;
error_too_big:  fprintf(stderr, "Error: too big\n");     return (mode_t)-1;
}
```

[I've totally glossed over the question of whether or not the type is signed or unsigned and just assumed unsigned here]

PS, yes, I have "secret knowledge" that no valid mode is likely to exceed 0177777; please ignore that as it is not necessarily true for other predefined types of its ilk.

PPS, junk like `time_t` which might not even be integral is not a part of this question

**EDIT** Added in the error goop.
Also, note that all leading whitespace has been skipped prior to this being called.

Comment: Please post your code unchanged. Now that you omitted some parts the code is not longer valid `c` code and thus off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative would be to store the value, then test whether any truncation occured:

```
m = u;
if (m != u) goto error_too_big;
```

I think some of the single-character variables (`e`, `u`, `c`, etc.) could be given better names.  The next person to modify the code (which could be Future You) will pick it up more quickly if it has meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 2):

### `strtou...()` allows a leading '-'

It looks like OP wants to fail negative values and does catch many potential ones.  `if (*s == '-' )` is insufficient detection for inputs like `"  -123"`.  `strtou...()` curiously allows a `'-'` sign, simply negating the unsigned value, so that is no help.  Instead, code could  first find the first non-white-space.

```
if ( s == NULL) goto error_no_value;
if (*s == '\0') goto error_no_value;
while (isspace((unsigned char) *s)) s++;
if (*s == '-' ) goto error_negative;
```

OP may want to allow input like `"-0"`, yet leave that to another day.  Assume that is invalid.

### `isspace(char))` pitfall

`isspace(int x)` is well defined for all values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  As `char` may have an offending  negative value, consider the below instead which also allows for multiple trailing white space.

```
// c = *e;
// if (c && !isspace(c)) goto error_bogus;
while (isspace((unsigned char) *e)) e++;
if (*e) goto error_bogus;
```

### better way??

If we *know* the target type is some unsigned type, simply compare to `(mode_t) -1`.  It is well defined and always the maximum value.

```
#define UMAX ((mode_t) -1)

if (u > UMAX) goto error_too_big;
```

Values that are too big should consider setting `errno` for the calling code's use and setting to the max value.

```
if (u > UMAX) {
  m = max;
  errno = ERANGE;
  goto error_too_big;
}
```

---

If the type may be some *signed* type, highly portable code is not truly possible.  With `sizeof (mystery_type) == sizeof(int32_t)`, we can conclude that `MYSTERY_TYPE_MAX <= 0x7FFFFFFF`, yet we cannot absolutely conclude `MYSTERY_TYPE_MAX == 0x7FFFFFFF`, even if it is highly probable.  These are implementation defined issues and portable code uses defines to drive that.  With nominally portable code, using compares, as in OP's code, is OK with various signed types.  Be mindful that `intN_t` types are semi-optional - although quite common.

```
// Use fixed width types
if (sizeof m == sizeof(int32_t)) max = INT32_MAX;
...

// or use standard types
if (sizeof m == sizeofint)) max = INT_MAX;
...
```

Comment: You might want to put the `while(isspace())` loop before the test for `'\0'` - a space-only input is as invalid as an empty input, I think.

Comment: @TobySpeight Could go there, yet OP's code catches that later with `if (e == s) goto error_bogus;`

Comment: I added a comment that all leading WS has already been skipped prior to this being called.  Also this routined does not need to worry about trailing WS as that is also handled elseweher.  Also, don't want to accept "-0" (is there a reason you might want to?)

Comment: When I use `isspace()` with anything but an `int` argument I get a compiler warning about non-int array index.  Not sure how to reconcile this with your suggestion.

Comment: @JohnHascall Changing your code once answers arrive typically results in a roll-back or DV.  Consider amending  See [After you ask your question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions/2439#2439)

Comment: @JohnHascall "don't want to accept "-0" (is there a reason you might want to?)" --> As that results in a valid `mode_t` is a reason to accept it.  Your call.

Comment: @JohnHascall 1) What the offending code `isspace((unsigned char) *s)`?  What compiler, what options.  Could use `isspace((int)(unsigned char) *s)`.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm stuck.  One guy says "have to have it", one says "can't add it".

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> /* now the question part -- better way??? */
>        if (sizeof(mode_t) == 1) x = UINT8_MAX;
>   else if (sizeof(mode_t) == 2) x = UINT16_MAX;
>   else if (sizeof(mode_t) == 4) x = UINT32_MAX;
>   else if (sizeof(mode_t) == 8) x = UINT64_MAX;
> ```

The maximum size for any unsigned integer is 2^n-1 for n bits. We know there are 8 bits in a byte (sizeof returns the number of bytes), and 2^n = 1 << n.

so the result is simply:

```
x = (1ull << (sizeof m * CHAR_BIT) - 1)
```

Comment: I meant for the other `1` - the one you're shifting: `(1ull << (sizeof m * CHAR_BIT) - 1)`.  Oh, and we *don't* know there are 8 bits in a `char`, so this fixes that error, too.

Comment: @TobySpeight  Note:, if `UINT8_MAX` is defined, then `CHAR_BIT == 8` must be true.  Still good to avoid naked magic numbers.

Comment: Is there a danger that `(1ull << (sizeof m * CHAR_BIT)` will overflow?

Comment: @JohnHascall `1ull << (sizeof m * CHAR_BIT)` could overflow when `sizeof m > sizeof (unsigned long long)`.  Not likely today, maybe in 20 yrs.

Comment: What about `sizeof m == sizeof (unsigned long long)`?  Or `sizeof x == sizeof  m`?